# Ok to install standard heatsink in PowerMac G4?

Tags: mac, heatsink, powerpc

So, I had told my brother that I needed a good PC for schoolwork, and he gave me a PowerMac G4, and told me that I would need to dust it, as he hadn't used it in years.

Upon taking it apart, I took off the MONSTER heatsink it had in it (about a 4 inx4 in heatsink) to see what socket the PowerPC CPU was (It's soldered onto the mobo), and I noticed it had screw holes for a normal PC heatsink/fan assembly (2 inx 2.5 in I think), and I was wondering if this would lower performance at all, by possibly producing higher temps. Would it be OK to use a standard heatsink?

Comment: A powermac g4 isn't a 'good pc', its a minor museum piece

Comment: @JourneymanGeek It's good for schoolwork (and Quake 3 Arena), and I've heard that the highest-end model had a clockspeed measured in the MHz. Not sure why, but the one I got has 1.25GHz clockspeed and 1.25GB of DDR RAM. Java programming for school? Perfect PC. And yes, I use the word PC because the of the nomenclature of the term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt the screw holes would line up correctly with a standard PC heatsink, but even if they did, there are no headers on the mobo to run the fan.  That monster heatsink is there because the only fan keeping it cool is the large case fan under the optical drive bays.

Apple has always put a lot of thought into their case designs, and their priority has always been quiet over cold.  They allow their hardware to run a little on the hot side, keeping things just cool enough to avoid making noise and without throttling the CPU.  If that heatsink isn't damaged, I'd recommend keeping it because anything smaller will just make it run louder and it won't improve performance.

Also, it should be noted that toward the end of the PowerPC days, they ran notoriously hot, and yours was the model right before that became a huge problem for them.  The late-model G5s were so hot that Apple started liquid cooling them.  They weren't heatsinks at that point as much as they were radiators.  It's one of the biggest reasons they switched to Intel.  The 2005 PowerMac G5 has the [biggest cooling block I've ever seen](http://home.k07.itscom.net/jf1dcu/Macintosh_Folder/PowerMac_G5_Dual_25GHz.jpg) on a desktop computer.

Comment: After testing (not actually booting up with it), a standard heatsink did in fact fit. I have a CPU cooling assembly from a Dell Optiplex 170l, which didn't have a fan above the heatsink. I will stick with the standard heatsink though. But about that cooling block - those two things that say 'G5' - are THOSE the cooling block?

Comment: Oh hellz yeah that's the cooler!  [Here's an article with pics of a disassembled one](http://www.overclockers.com.au/article.php?id=307166). [Here's a pic of a coolant leak](http://www.macnews.com/content_images/macsimum/uploads/G5Coolant.jpg). (Note they actually used antifreeze!). [Here's what the power supply looks like afterward](http://torontomactech.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/IMG_0827.jpg). After that it was easy to see why they switched to Intel.  It should also be noted that this is from a 2005 model.  Yours is a 2003 or 2004 model, so not so far behind that monstrosity.